# Angular2 quickstart: how should I include a new npm package?

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I setup the environment by cloning the angular2 quick start repo: https://github.com/angular/quickstart. After I added new package into system.config.js file, the app runs but "npm test" failed. I noticed that there is an empty file named systemjs.config.extras.js, should I add some code there?

Question:
how should add a new npm package to angular2 quick start example so that both "npm start" and "npm test" can pass?

Comment: did npm test work before attempting adding in a new package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I added new package into system.config.js file, the app runs but "npm test" failed

I'm assuming you are using Karma. What you need to do is add that third-party lib to the `files` array in the `karma.conf.js` file.

How it works is that karma starts a server, and adds all the files listed in the `files` array, to the list of files that the server is available to serve. So when SystemJS tries to load the file, if it is not in the karma `files`, then the file doesn't exist on the server. So you will get a 404 when trying to retrieve that file from SystemJS.

Comment: Yes, the quick start repo use Karma for testing. The way you mentioned seems not good for maintain: whenever there is a new package added, you need to add it in both system.config.js and karma.conf.js files.

I thought systemjs.config.extras.js may be used for adding new package there and be shared by both functionality implementation and testing. Or I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try angular-cli which is the recommended way to work with angular2.
To create a new project you have to install angular-cli with the command

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

then you can create a new angular2 project with

```
ng new your-new-project-name
```

and finally to add a new global dependency by following this guide (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation). I reproduce the content here for bootstrap.

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

Then add the needed script files to `apps[0].script`s in `agular-cli.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the `apps[0].styles` array in `agular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

Finally you can deploy your application using ng serve from the root of the newly created project.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, our team already decided not to use angular-cli, part of the reason is it seems doesn't work well with PhpStorm IDE.
So I have to work based on the quick start example.